# Devise signed_in user giving 401 unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I have a rails application and I'm adding a feature to auto-login users using confirmation tokens sent to them as a part of the URL in email links.

I added the following to my `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :bypass_login

  private
  def bypass_login
    if params[:some_params]
      some_params = params[:some_params]
      if some_params[:token] && some_params[:client_email]
        user = User.by_bypass_token(some_params[:token])
        sign_in(user, :bypass => true) if user

        puts "We should have a current user over here #{current_user}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the above, the puts does show me a `current_user`in the terminal but it still seems to throw an error and not really login the user. The terminal response is:

```
Processing by ErrorsController#routing as */*
  Parameters: {"some_params"=>
  {"client_email"=>"some@example.com", "token"=>"iasSDagLadgdagB"}, "a"=>"api/v1/player/game_play"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login_bypass_token" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["login_bypass_token", "2464l6nbjb416vi4v64iv64iva25a44326363yhvyivg234624646"]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  We should have a current user over here #<User:0x007fc215c58b48>
  Completed 401 Unauthorized in 322ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

So it's showing an errorController#routing and 401 Unauthorized even though the user should be signed in before reaching any other controller. Do I need to add something more over here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using devise's `sign_in` in the after-confirmation redirection? eg:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  private
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    your_new_after_confirmation_path
  end
end
```